# Component using props function in the initialization instead of individuality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I just started to learn react.

I got the parent component:Scrum which passes to the child:MissionList func in the props.

the parent is

```
var Scrum = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        secondsStopTime: 0,
        minutesStopTime: 0,
        hoursStopTime: 0,
        titleInput: "",
        contentInput: "",
        ownerInput: "",
        missions: []
    };
},
handleDelete: function (index) {
  console.log('handle delete was pressed with index' ,index);
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
                <MissionList missions={this.state.missions} onDelete={this.handleDelete}/>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

the child: MissionList is:

```
var MissionList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<div>
            {this.props.missions.map(function (mission, index) {
                console.log(this);
                return (<div key={index} className="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div className="alert alert-info">
                        <strong>{index + 1}</strong>

                        <input type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-xs delete-button "
                                onClick={this.props.onDelete(index)} value="X"/>
                    </div>
                </div>);
            }.bind(this))}
        </div>);
    }
});
```

As you can see I pass the onDelete function to the MissionList. When I inspect the component in the console, I see that the print of "handle delete was pressed with index 0" occurs only in the initialization of the Mission List.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try change `this.props.onDelete(index)` to `this.props.onDelete.bind(this, index)`, because in first case you call function immediately, but you need call it when you click on element

Comment: the solution worked, but I got this Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance. See Scrum

Comment: You can change the `.bind(this, index)` to `.bind(null, index)` to fix that issue, since React automatically binds component methods when using `createClass`.

Comment: thank you it worked,but can you explain why? (more deeply)